# Connection failure to SAP HANA from Sqoop SAP DBTech JDBC: [414]: user is forced to change password

Tags: java, hadoop, jdbc, hana, sqoop2

Though the User id and password is correct, I am getting below error message.

Please let me know if you have any solution.

In SAP HANA - HIVE Table.

> ```
> Warning: /apps/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.2.0-1.cdh5.2.0.p0.36/bin/../lib/sqoop/../accumulo does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail.
> Please set $ACCUMULO_HOME to the root of your Accumulo installation.
> 15/01/20 10:30:15 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.5-cdh5.2.0
> 15/01/20 10:30:15 WARN tool.BaseSqoopTool: Setting your password on the command-line is insecure. Consider using -P instead.
> 15/01/20 10:30:15 INFO tool.BaseSqoopTool: Using Hive-specific delimiters for output. You can override
> 15/01/20 10:30:15 INFO tool.BaseSqoopTool: delimiters with --fields-terminated-by, etc.
> 15/01/20 10:30:15 INFO teradata.TeradataManagerFactory: Loaded connector factory for 'Cloudera Connector Powered by Teradata' on version 1.2c5
> 15/01/20 10:30:15 WARN sqoop.ConnFactory: Parameter --driver is set to an explicit driver however appropriate connection manager is not being set (via --connection-manager).
>   Sqoop is going to fall back to org.apache.sqoop.manager.GenericJdbcManager. Please specify explicitly which connection manager should be used next time.
> 15/01/20 10:30:15 INFO manager.SqlManager: Using default fetchSize of 1000
> 15/01/20 10:30:15 INFO tool.CodeGenTool: Beginning code generation
> 15/01/20 10:30:16 ERROR manager.SqlManager: Error executing statement:
>   com.sap.db.jdbc.exceptions.JDBCDriverException: SAP DBTech JDBC: [414]: user is forced to change password: alter password required for user CH1HAHSGPOC
>   com.sap.db.jdbc.exceptions.JDBCDriverException: SAP DBTech JDBC: [414]: user is forced to change password: alter password required for user CH1HAHSGPOC
>         at com.sap.db.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionSapDB.createException(SQLExceptionSapDB.java:334)
>         at com.sap.db.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionSapDB.generateDatabaseException(SQLExceptionSapDB.java:174)
>         at com.sap.db.jdbc.packet.ReplyPacket.buildExceptionChain(ReplyPacket.java:102)
> ```

Comment: I think this may be off-topic because there's nothing to indicate that this is a programming-related question and/or a reproducible general issue.

Comment: Hi ,I could manage to do this using sap jdbc driver. The password was about to change and hence error was throwing. DBA modified the password and it solved the prob.

Comment: Then this is definitely off-topic.

Comment: @user3858193 How did you managed? I am facing same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@hafizmujadid  when there is a password expiration deadline comes , it throws these error. What you have to do is ask the team from Sap Hana side to change the password. This solved my problem and it may be yours.